# What options are there for caching SQL data?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server that is accessed by a simulation server.

The simulation server runs 70 processes (C# instances) that each request the SAME large data table from SQL Server and run a simulation (with different parameters) on it.

This slows down my SQL Server greatly, and I see CPU usage maxing out on the activity monitor.

Several questions:

1. So is this really causing SQL Server to slow down? I have created all the indexes my query suggested. I thought sql server had inbuilt smart caching that would alleviate such repeated requests. Perhaps I have not set it up correctly?
2. If this is a problem, and I need to cache data locally on my simulation server. Is there some "SQL remote app" that could do this for me? Or do I need to create my own data caching app in C#?

Comment: The SQL Server engine only caches data pages in memory so it doesn't have to hit the disk. It never caches query results, so a query that's resource intensive because it crunches data will be resource intensive every time you run it. Caching query results is something you can build, but requires considerable effort to ensure the cache remains valid. Usually it's a better idea to rethink your query strategy to ensure more is done in the individual query (passing parameter settings in a table-valued parameter and returning results for all of them, for example). Plus basic optimizing, of course.

Comment: You might want to follow this guide to delve a little further: http://dba-datascience.com/high-cpu-usage-sql-server/ This would be an interesting one to troubleshoot. It might be that rewriting your queries or altering the SQL Server config will help. Or it might just be that this workload is better suited to a different platform (like some kind of SMP or datalake / databricks setup)

Comment: ... and sometimes if your SQL Server runs out of memory, CPU hits 100% because it's so busy paging. This doesn't sound like your situation but it illustrates the complexity.